# IOS image asset visible in interface builder but not in running app

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been programming in IOS for less than two weeks now, so please excuse me if there's an obvious solution here.

I've got a problem with one of three buttons on a welcome screen. The xib file looks fine in the interface builder, but when I run the app on a device the topmost button disappears. As this behavior is unique to iphones only (physical and simulated) and not iPads, I was able to trace the bug to the iphone image asset I use for the button. For some reason it won't display outside of the interface builder, while other images render just fine. It might also be helpful to note that the button still works, it's just not visible.

Is there any likely cause of this? I'd be grateful for any insight or advice.

Comment: Tell us more about how the the image is added to your project. Is it in the asset catalog?

Answer (score 0):

If an image is inside a folder in your app's bundle, you can't access it just by calling `UIImage(named:)` with the image file's name. That's what happens at runtime, so display of the image fails. But Interface Builder doesn't realize that; it wrongly displays the image anyway.